# How to sum correlation, or, calculate correlation of disjointed variables

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, finance

I'm trying to calculate the correlation of 2 array of variables, but the array is disjointed in the middle - but I'm trying to obtain one correlation coefficient

**See the excel file I uploaded:**

[question]http://www.speedyshare.com/pdzDX/Correlation-question.xlsx

because the disjoint in the middle, there is somewhat a jump in value and when I correlate the whole set of variable together I obtain a correlation coefficient that is not really reflective of the relationship between the variables

How would I be able to calculate one correlation coefficient? I can calculate two separate correlations but is there anyway to sum 2 correlation together?

Comment: you will have better luck with this Q on http://stats.stackexchange.com/?as=1